# Rails mass-assign for admin users

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using rolify to manage user roles and when I try to update the roles via a user form I receive this:

```
can't mass-assign protected attributes: role_ids
```

This is comforting, but it has me wondering, how do I then allow admin to update user roles via mass-assign yet not allow normal users to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a different `attr_accessible` list inside your `User` model:

```
attr_accessible :name
attr_accessible :name, :role_ids, :as => :admin
```

And then inside the `create` and `update` actions for your admin controller:

```
User.create(params[:user], :as => :admin)

user.update_attributes(params[:user], :as => :admin)
```

Comment: Here's a good blog post with more details: http://launchware.com/articles/whats-new-in-edge-scoped-mass-assignment-in-rails-3-1

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure if you've used inherited_resources, but I have a related question based on this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13299278/inherited-resources-how-to-update-attributes-with-as